# Stdout maxBuffer length exceeded in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, stdout, spawn

I have the following block of code

```
> reasoner = new Reasoner({
>   type: 'local', 
>   folder: 'csp_files' 
> });
> 
> console.log("solving Model");
> reasoner.solve(Model, (err, stdout, stderr, isSatisfiable) => {
>   console.log("isSatisfiable");
>   console.log(isSatisfiable);
>   if (err) {
>       // manage error
>       console.log("model error");
>       future_response.return("model error");
>   } else {
>       // manage solution
>       console.log(stdout);
>       console.log(isSatisfiable);
>       future_response.return(stdout);
>   }
> });
> console.log("Model solved");
> return future_response.wait();
```

and I get the error attached in the img
[image]

I have tried increasing the buffer size using this

```
reasoner.solve(usCspModel, {maxBuffer : 500 * 1024}, (err, stdout, stderr, isSatisfiable) =>
```

but didn't help at all..., any suggestions?

Comment: What is `Reasoner` and what is `Model` here? Can you link documentation or code on these too?

Comment: thank you @Jankapunkt https://www.npmjs.com/package/governify-csp-tools they are both derived from a npm library attached above. Just to mention that the code was returning answer when the file that was created was smaller, now I had to work with larger files that is why I believe I get this message and I need to increase the buffersize somehow..

Comment: Doing this: `console.log(stdout)` doesn't make sense, usually stdout is a handle to the output stream of the process. Maybe just think of something else to log here, and the problem will probably go away

Comment: I commented the `console.log(stdout)` but still get the same error...what should I use to log larger files if this it the problem as I can understand?

Comment: From what I have read I should use `spawn` to rewrite stdout but how can that be replaced in the aforementioned block of code?